# What does the Red heifer supposed to mean?

Tags: taamei-mitzvot-reasons, parah-adumah

I've seen references to the importance of the Red Heifer as an eschatological sign of the coming Messianic Age. What is it supposed to mean?

Comment: It means a lot of things to Jews, as well as non-Jews.  Just Google "red heifer eschatology" and see all the stuff that comes up.

Comment: Can you give examples or references to what you have seen, to increase the chances of getting a good answer? Asking what a given one or two of them means would be much more answerable and would give potential answerers something to analyze.

Comment: @DoubleeAA I suspect that taamei-hamitzvot tag is inappropriate, as the OP refers not to the significance of the mitzva, but to the significance of the cow itself; that is, of finding one. | Regardless, the OP should edit to clarify.

Comment: NB. Rabbi Emanuel Feldman describes in _Tales out of Shul_ how he once gave a sermon on the topic, after which someone approached him and thanked him for the sermon, but wanted to know "what is the ritual of the Red Pepper?"

Comment: Do you mean that we would be unable to bring a red heifer until the temple is rebuilt when the mashiach comes? Rav Moshe Feinstein once pointed out that the birth of a red heifer might be a sign of delay in the coming of mashiach as it must be a minimum age to be brought for the ritual. As a result, once the mashiach comes, then we will find one of the appropriate age to bring.

Comment: I learnt of the Red Heifer idea from a South Park episode ("Ginger Cow"). I'm trying to clarify the theological meaning of that episode.